# iOS: Firefox - How can I delete a desktop bookmark

Tags: ios, firefox, bookmarks

I installed Firefox on my iOS device and logged into my Firefox (Sync) account. In the Bookmarks screen I have a "Desktop Bookmarks" folder with my normal bookmarks. Nice! On of them is my reading list, and when I am done with a bookmark I want to delete it from that folder.

Unfortunately when I open a bookmark from the "Desktop Bookmarks" folder, the "burger button" (three lines, middle button in footer bar) pane doesn't show a blue star with "Remove Bookmark", but an empty star with "Add Bookmark" - so I can not "unclick" it to remove my bookmark but I create a new bookmark on my smartphone, which is then synced into the "Mobile Bookmarks" folder to my desktop Firefox.

I also found no way to remove the bookmark in the bookmark menu itself - swiping, long click etc. do nothing.

The only workaround I found was to indeed bookmark the page again on Firefox iOS so it get synced back, then use the "Mobile Bookmarks" folder on desktop to remove both bookmarks in both folders. This works, but I have to remember to do this.

**How can I delete a desktop bookmark via Firefox on iOS directly?**

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do this. The iOS Firefox lets me delete bookmarks I added from iOS Firefox, but not bookmarks I added from desktop Firefox.

Comment: Yes, they really need to fix this bug!